How do you pass values through a XAML command call?
I am new to wpf devexprss controls. trying to use a relaycommand to execute code in my viewmodel. I got the method to execute when I click save but the value is null. I want to grab an identifier from the table and pass it to a method in the view model. The code is in the context menu save and save as. and the code that I got to execute in the view model is below the XML in a separate code block
<Grid>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
<dxg:GridControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Attachments}">
    <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
        <dxg:GridColumn
            Width="Auto"
            AllowEditing="False"
            FieldName="AttachedFileName"
            Header="{x:Static properties:Resources.column_caption_attached_file_name}"
            HeaderToolTip="{x:Static properties:Resources.column_tooltip_attached_file_name}"
            ShowInColumnChooser="True"
            Visible="True"
            VisibleIndex="0" />
        <dxg:GridColumn
            Width="Auto"
            AllowEditing="False"
            FieldName="Extension"
            Header="{x:Static properties:Resources.column_caption_filetype}"
            HeaderToolTip="{x:Static properties:Resources.column_tooltip_filetype}"
            ShowInColumnChooser="True"
            Visible="True"
            VisibleIndex="1" />
        <dxg:GridColumn
            Width="Auto"
            AllowEditing="False"
            FieldName="StepName"
            Header="{x:Static properties:Resources.column_caption_step_name}"
            HeaderToolTip="{x:Static properties:Resources.column_tooltip_step_name}"
            ShowInColumnChooser="True"
            Visible="True"
            VisibleIndex="2" />
        <dxg:GridColumn
            Width="Auto"
            AllowEditing="False"
            FieldName="StepRecycleCount"
            Header="{x:Static properties:Resources.column_caption_step_recycle_count}"
            HeaderToolTip="{x:Static properties:Resources.column_tooltip_step_recycle_count}"
            ShowInColumnChooser="True"
            Visible="True"
            VisibleIndex="3" />
        <dxg:GridColumn
            Width="Auto"
            FieldName="StepIsRecycled"
            Header="{x:Static properties:Resources.column_caption_recycled}"
            HeaderToolTip="{x:Static properties:Resources.column_tooltip_recycled}"
            HorizontalHeaderContentAlignment="Center"
            ShowInColumnChooser="True"
            Visible="True"
            VisibleIndex="4">
            <dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesome}"
                        FontSize="16"
                        Foreground="Gray"
                        Text="{Binding Value, Converter={StaticResource BoolToCheckImageConverter}}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
        </dxg:GridColumn>
        <dxg:GridColumn
            Width="Auto"
            AllowEditing="False"
            FieldName="StepSequenceNumber"
            Header="{x:Static properties:Resources.column_caption_step_sequence_number}"
            HeaderToolTip="{x:Static properties:Resources.column_tooltip_step_sequence_number}"
            HorizontalHeaderContentAlignment="Right"
            ShowInColumnChooser="True"
            Visible="True"
            VisibleIndex="5" />
        <dxg:GridColumn
            Width="Auto"
            AllowEditing="False"
            FieldName="Comment"
            Header="{x:Static properties:Resources.column_caption_comment}"
            HeaderToolTip="{x:Static properties:Resources.column_tooltip_comment}"
            ShowInColumnChooser="True"
            Visible="True"
            VisibleIndex="6" />
    </dxg:GridControl.Columns>


    <dxg:GridControl.View>
        <dxg:TableView
            AllowEditing ="False"
            BestFitMode="VisibleRows"
            FocusedRow="{Binding FocusedAttachment, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
            ShowGroupPanel="False"
            ShowIndicator="False" />
    </dxg:GridControl.View>
    <dxg:GridControl.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Save" Command="{Binding SaveFileCommand}"  CommandParameter="{Binding Path=FocusedRowData.AttachedFileName, ElementName=tableView}" />
            <MenuItem Header="Save As.." Command="{Binding SaveFileAsCommand}" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </dxg:GridControl.ContextMenu>
</dxg:GridControl>

[RelayCommand]
private void OnSaveFile(object testpointIdentifier)
{

}
[RelayCommand]
private void OnSaveFileAs()
{

}

